# Do system table modifications pass through replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-metadata

I am currently patching a Postgres 9.6 database.

As part of the patch I'm required to make changes to the system tables, first changing `allow_system_table_mods` in the config file, then executing the recommended SQL.

If I make this change on a master db, does it get replicated to other slave databases, or do I need to make this change on all DBs round robin ?

Comment: You're doing this on a production server? And need to ask questions on Stackoverflow? That sounds... exciting to me.

Comment: no... this requires a change to the config and a restart, I wondered if this config change needs to exist on all standbys before a change is issued on the master, my question could have been clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform modifications on standby servers, as they are read-only.

Any change to the PostgreSQL cluster will be replicated; the clusters are identical copies of each other. This includes catalog modifications.

Modifying the catalog is not supported, and you are on your own if you get in trouble. Moreover, any such changes will be lost after a major upgrade.

You should *not* do this, **except** when the release notes tell you to do so after an upgrade (to fix a bug).

Comment: The docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/release-9-6-4.html state this change should be made for existing databases

Comment: If the release notes tell you to perform catalog modifications after an upgrade, you can do it.